# Node to string without parent information

Tags: java, xml, xpath, transform, w3c

I use xpath to get a NodeList. Then I use this code to get a string representation, but it also has the parent nodes.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sw.toString();
```

How can I only get the self or decendant as string? And maybe steal the namespace declariations from the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how the nodes in the node-set were selected. Most probably they are elements and this is the cause of your problem.

**The solution is simple**:

Construct and use an XPath expression that selects only the wanted **text nodes**.

**For example, instead of** :

```
/x/y/z
```

**use**

```
/x/y/z/text()
```

The last expression selects any text node that is a child of any element named `z` that is a child of any element named `y` that is a child of the top element, named `x`.

**UPDATE**:

The OP has clarified in a comment:

> "Thanks, I tried this, but it only gives my real text in node. I want
>   a string reresentation of everything (nodes and text) in the current
>   node, without the information of the parent nodes. E.g if I would just
>   have a xml file and open it with a text editor and then copy out some
>   subtree. Do you know what I'm talking about?"

**This can be accomplished in XSLT, using**

```
<xsl:copy-of select="yourExpression/node()"/>
```

Alternatively, if your XML API allows it, for every selected node use:

```
theSelectedNode.InnerXml
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it only gives my real text in node. I want a string reresentation of everything (nodes and text) in the current node, without the information of the parent nodes. E.g if I would just have a xml file and open it with a text editor and then copy out some subtree. Do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: @FranzKafka: Yes, now i know what you want. See the update to my question.